# PDO_SQLSRV is running very slow in symfony?

Tags: sql-server, symfony, sqlsrv

I am setting up symfony + MSSQL. But the queries are running very slow.

```
Symfony version : 3.4
PHP Version: 7.2
ODBC Version: 13
```

Following config has been used:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
driver: pdo_sqlsrv
host: '%database_host%'
port: '%database_port%'
dbname: '%database_name%'
user: '%database_user%'
password: '%database_password%'
charset: UTF8
MultipleActiveResultSets: true
```

I also tried connection pooling from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-pooling-microsoft-drivers-for-php-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017
This doesn't help.

Symfony Code:

```
$integration = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Integrations')->find($integrationID);
```

```
$customer = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Customers')->find($customerID);
```

Time taken by first statement is almost similar as time taken to run both the statements.

Is it taking time to connect to the SQL Server Database?

Comment: Any lead is appreciable